# Replace a sentence in ORACLE using REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

I Would like to remove all occurences of the below pattern in my string.

```
SUPPLEMENTAL LOG GROUP "SAMPLESL" ("PIKEY") ALWAYS, 
SUPPLEMENTAL LOG GROUP "SAMPLE2" ("UIKEY") ALWAYS,
```

How do I create a regular expression for this?

Essentially, I do not want any SUPPLEMENTAL LOG GROUP statements. This is generated by dbms_metadata.get_ddl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
WITH cte(R) as (select 
'CREATE TABLE TAB (X int)
--- something
SUPPLEMENTAL LOG GROUP "SAMPLESL" ("PIKEY") ALWAYS, 
SUPPLEMENTAL LOG GROUP "SAMPLE2" ("UIKEY") ALWAYS, 
--else
'
  FROM DUAL
)
select R, regexp_replace(R, 'SUPPLEMENTAL LOG GROUP.*', '')
from CTE;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0675f6452a58437605cf9685a750886f)**

Answer (score 0):

You may also use `DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM` to set the `CONSTRAINTS` ( which includes SUPPLEMENTAL LOG GROUP) to false before running `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL`. But the problem is that this will also disable the display of all other non-referential table constraints. I feel Oracle should have had `SUPPLEMENTAL LOG GROUP` as a separate *Transform 
parameter*.

```
EXEC DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,
'CONSTRAINTS',
       FALSE);


select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','YOURTABLE','YOURSCHEMA') ddl from dual;
```

Refer [**SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_metada.htm#i1000135) for more options.

Comment: Yes, I could not use this because I still need the other constraints.